# recovering from transaction failure in php

Tags: php, mysqli

SQL queries can fail for a number of reasons, even though the same query ran 100 times before without a problem. I'd like to detect weather a transaction failed. I found 2 ways of doing this:

1: use a ton of if else statements

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (?,?,?)");
if ( false===$stmt ) {
  $mysqli->rollback();
  issueInternalError();
}

$rc = $stmt->bind_param('iii', $x, $y, $z);
if ( false===$rc ) {
  $mysqli->rollback();
  issueInternalError();
}
$rc = $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$rc ) {
  $mysqli->rollback();
  issueInternalError();
}else{
$mysqli->commit();
}

$stmt->close();
```

2: perform query in try catch block

```
try{
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $x, $y, $z);
    $stmt->execute();
    $mysqli->commit();

}catch(Exception $e){
    $mysqli->rollback();
    issueInternalError();
}
```

Using try/catch halves the code and it makes it really readable, but will the second code correctly catch all possible errors? or better will `issueInternalError()` always be executed if an error exists?

UPDATE:

I've added this code to the beginning of php file

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

I am getting mixed results in my tests:

This kind of error is catched successfully:

```
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('iiissss', $x, $y, $z); //error here is successfully catched
```

but this isn't

```
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $x, $y, $z,""); //error not catched
```

It looks like the second one is not caused by mysqli, therefore it isn't thrown.

Comment: As long as you remember to [configure mysqli to throw exceptions instead of errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php), it's fine.

Comment: I think I made my question confusing. I am not worried about SQL injection, but rather identifying whether transaction was successful.

Comment: @sanjihan You can actually just test it for yourself. Try executing an invalid query and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try-catch will not catch all errors. It will only catch exceptions. There's a difference between errors and exceptions in PHP.

The following try-catch will catch only exceptions:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```

To catch both exceptions and errors you can use `Throwable` interface. As a side note, it is best to always provide fully specified name for classes and interfaces in PHP.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch(\Throwable $e) {
    // ...
}
```

Mysqli can throw both exceptions and errors. Exceptions are usually triggered when mysqli can't process a command or the execution of the command failed on the MySQL server-side. These exceptions are instances of `mysqli_sql_exception` exception class.

If there is a programmer error on the PHP side, e.g. an incorrect number of arguments or invalid arguments, then mysqli will trigger a PHP error. These can be various errors, but usually, they all derive from the base class `Error`.

**Warning**: Prior to PHP 8 many errors were simply warnings. These have been properly categorized now. Additionally, a number of software bugs were fixed in mysqli that didn't trigger an exception when one should occur. For best result, please use the latest PHP release.